# Google Sheets Formula Parse Error If,Then large formula not working

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Okay, so I have checked this formula several times over in google sheets.

Brief explanation: This is a God Tier leveling system for a role-playing sheet. I had fixed several things I had found wrong with it but now I don't see anything wrong at all. It is getting very frustrating. It worked for the lower system but not for this one. I don't understand it.

=IF(C28<100, "0", IF(C28<5000, "1", IF(C28<6000, "2", IF(C28<7000, "3", IF(C28<8000, "4", IF(C28<9000, "5", IF(C28<10000, "6", IF(C28<12000, "7", IF(C28<14000, "8", IF(C28<16000, "9", IF(C28<18000, "10", IF(C28<20000, "11", IF(C28<23000, "12", IF(C28<26000, "13", IF(C28<29000, "14", IF(C28<32000, "15", IF(C28<35000, "16", IF(C28<38000, "17", IF(C28<41000, "18", IF(C28<44000, "19", IF(C28<47000, "20", IF(C28<50000, "21", IF(C28<54000, "22", IF(C28<58000, "23", IF(C28<62000, "24", IF(C28<66000, "25", IF(C28<70000, "26", IF(C28<74000, "27", IF(C28<78000, "28", IF(C28<82000, "29", IF(C28<86000, "30", IF(C28<90000, "31", IF(C28<95000, "32", IF(C28<100000, "33", IF(C28<105000, "34", IF(C28<110000, "35", IF(C28<115000, "36", IF(C28<120000, "37", IF(C28<125000, "38", IF(C28<130000, "39", IF(C40<135000, "40", IF(C28<140000, "41", IF(C28<146000, "42", IF(C28<152000, "43", IF(C28<158000, "44", IF(C28<164000, "45", IF(C28<170000, "46", IF(C28<176000, "47", IF(C28<182000, "48", IF(C28<188000, "49", IF(C28<194000, "50", IF(C28<200000, "51", IF(C28<207000, "52", IF(C28<214000, "53", IF(C28<221000, "54", IF(C28<228000, "55", IF(C28<235000, "56", IF(C28<242000, "57", IF(C28<249000, "58", IF(C28<256000, "59", IF(C28<263000, "60", IF(C28<270000, "61", IF(C28<278000, "62", IF(C28<286000, "63", IF(C28<294000, "64", IF(C28<302000, "65", IF(C28<310000, "66", IF(C28<318000, "67", IF(C28<326000. "68", IF(C28<334000, "69", IF(C28<342000, "70", IF(C28<350000, "71", IF(C28<359000, "72", IF(C28<368000, "73", IF(C28<377000, "74", IF(C28<386000, "75", IF(C28<395000, "76", IF(C28<404000, "77", IF(C28<413000, "78", IF(C28<422000, "79", IF(C28<431000, "80", IF(C28<440000, "81", IF(C28<450000, "82", IF(C28<460000, "83", IF(C28<470000, "84", IF(C28<480000, "85", IF(C28<490000, "86", IF(C28<500000, "87", IF(C28<650000, "88", IF(C28<800000, "89", IF(C28<950000, "90", IF(C28<1100000, "91", IF(C28<1250000, "92", IF(C28<1400000, "93", IF(C28<1550000, "94", IF(C28<1700000, "95", IF(C28<1850000, "96", IF(C28<2000000, "97", IF(C28<2500000, "98", IF(C28<3000000, "99", IF(C28>2999999, "100")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Put your break down in a table and use a lookup function.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to do that but I will look it up and see if it will work.

Comment: on `IF(C28<326000. "68",` there is a period but it should be a comma.

Comment: You may refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587898/google-spreadsheet-multiple-if-statements-between-number-ranges/40768666#40768666). The best eay is using `vlookup` formula.

Answer (score 0):

You have a period between the 67 and 68 scores :

> "67", IF(C28<326000`.` "68",

it should be a `,`