# Use nested IF statements to change sparkline colors

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested-if, sparklines

I'm trying to color-code my sparklines based on percentage cutoffs.

I am able to do two colors but can't wrap my head around multiple ifs.

B1 has points possible of 3

1. B2 has points scored the first time
2. B3 has points scored the second time
3. B4 has a two-column sparkline.

   - B1 can vary from 2 to 8.
   - Would like to color code the sparklines where each column has its own colors based on the following percentage conditions of Cell B1

     1. `>0%` but `<50%` to be (RED)
     2. `>=50%` but `<75%` to be (ORANGE)
     3. `>=75%` but `<100%` to be (GREEN)
     4. `>100%` to be (BLUE)

I used the following formula to create two possible ones where the high color is blue or green.

```
=if(B3>B1,
 SPARKLINE(B2:B3,{"charttype","column";"color","red";"highcolor","blue";"ymin",0}),
 SPARKLINE(B2:B3,{"charttype","column";"color","red";"highcolor","green";"ymin",0}))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvzznbrsR0GdqEr6J52_aWOSFDAf0zYn9MxglzKRyfA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587898/multiple-if-statements-between-number-ranges

Answer (score 1):

nesting of `IF` statements is done like this:

```
=IF(B3 > B1, SPARKLINE(B2:B3,
             {"charttype", "column"; "color", "red"; "highcolor", "blue";  "ymin", 0}), 
 IF(B3 < B1, SPARKLINE(B2:B3,
             {"charttype", "column"; "color", "red"; "highcolor", "green"; "ymin", 0}), 
 IF(B3 = B1, SPARKLINE(B2:B3,
             {"charttype", "column"; "color", "red"; "highcolor", "pink";  "ymin", 0}), )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested OK in my GANTT sheet..
My ref cell is F24

```
If F24 <=30 "red"
If F24 <=95 "orange"
Else "Green"
So if F24 30="Red"  31<=>95"Orange" >95="Green"
=SE(F24<=30;SPARKLINE(F24;{"charttype"\"bar";"color1"\ "red";"max"\100});SE(F24<=95;SPARKLINE(F24;{"charttype"\"bar";"color1"\ "orange";"max"\100});SPARKLINE(F24;{"charttype"\"bar";"color1"\ "green";"max"\100})))
```